# Flyway - baseline tables are not created when history table is not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I am trying to use flyway but I come across the following problem.

Our database tables are already available in production landscape. Now to handle such a case, I am aware that I can make use of the baseline feature and put the DDL statements as part of the baseline script `V1.0.0__Initial_version.sql.` I am configuring flyway as follows:

```
Flyway.configure()
        .table(migrationTable)
        .cleanDisabled(true)
        .baselineOnMigrate(true)
        .createSchemas(false)
        .locations("flyway")      // files are present in resources:flyway
        .dataSource(dataSource)  //SAP Hana datasource
        .load()
```

What I observe is that, in a new landscape with a non-empty schema where the schema history is not found it is not executing the baseline script.. I could see that the schema history table is created with a row

```
installed_rank;version;
description;type;script;checksum;installed_by;installed_on;
execution_time;success
1;1;<< Flyway Baseline >>;BASELINE;<< Flyway Baseline >>;?;null;Apr 28, 2021 12:01:32.616 PM;0;1
```

But I am unable to find other tables in baseline script. I will really appreciate any help you can provide. I have searched for this and couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you are 'unable to find other tables in baseline script'? Did you expect those tables to be automagically created somehow? I recommend for you to read [this guide](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/existing) on how to work with existing schemas. TL;DR it tells you to either clean your schema, or make sure it is identical to production. There's nothing that suggests Flyway will somehow figure out how to handle a non-empty schema for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think the [baselineOnMigrate](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/baselineOnMigrate) feature will tell what it should do in case of a non-emty schema with no hostory table present. I suppose if the baselineOnMigrate is set, then the baseline script should also be executed.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the baseline is that you create a V1 script that is equivalent to your schema at the point where you start using Flyway; Flyway then does *not* run the migration, but you're in a state where it is effectively the same as if you'd written the V1 script and run it on an empty database.

You can then `clean` and `migrate`, or migrate a new **empty** database, and end up in the same place as your production.

However if you migrate a **non-empty** database with `baselineOnCreate(true)`, it will assume the V1 script corresponds to those objects that already exist and not run it.